# I cant change the value of variable Java?

Tags: java, variables, parameter-passing

I call this method with values that are first accepted in else if - which calls the method again with changed values. Then the values are accepted in if - there I want to change the value of sum2 and it gives correct answer in PrintLine but returns initial value - 0 ?? Many thanks. -Junior

```
private long remove(int k, long summ) {
        long sum2 = 0;
        Number smallest = heap.peek();
        
        if (smallest.occurancy >= k) {          
            int number = smallest.number;
            sum2 = (long) summ + (number*k); // ????????????????
            System.out.println(sum2 + " sum2"); // THIS IS CORRECT ???????????
            int newOccurancy = smallest.occurancy-k;
            heap.poll();
            heap.add(new Number(number, newOccurancy));         
        }
        
        else if (smallest.occurancy < k) {
                    int occurancysLeftInSmallest = smallest.occurancy;
                    summ+= smallest.number * occurancysLeftInSmallest; 
                    System.out.println(summ);
                    heap.poll(); 
                    k-=occurancysLeftInSmallest;  
                    remove(k, summ);                
        }
        return sum2; // BUT RETURNS 0 ???????????
    }
```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans summ is a parameter

Comment: Your problem is you don't use the return value of recursive `remove` call in the `else` condition and sum2 is never modified there

Comment: Let's do some debugging: you update `sum2` in your first `if` block, so: does that even kick in? What are `smallest.occurancy` and `k`?

Comment: Of course, added return remove(x,x) and put it in the beginning with if. Many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You return sum2, which is a local variable to the function and only lives till the end of the function. If you put sum2 in the class, it will work.

Comment: That's not how things work at all. The whole point of `return` with a return value is to get data out of a method.